# Blur webcam stream except the circle area in the center

Tags: html, video, webcam, blur

I use [photobooth](http://wolframhempel.github.com/photobooth-js/) in my MVC application.

On my page, I display the live webcam screen and I put a canvas element over the webcam screen, the code looks like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="700"></canvas>
<div id="videoStreamDiv" ></div>
```

What I want to complete is :I've drawed a circle on the canvas, I want the webcam stream area out the circle to be blurred.

**I've worked on this issue for few days,any help will be appreciate!**

Comment: show what you've worked on

Comment: I try to upload screenshot but my accounts needs 10 reputation to do that, here I give the screenshot link : current:http://www.geekpics.net/pkK     what I want:http://www.geekpics.net/pkl